# Android. ConstraintLayout: Place enough but scroll vertically. Why?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I use "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" in my test_layout.xml.

Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aabbcc">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/input_checkmark_on_green" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Z"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Z"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Z"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Here result (screenshot#1):

[image: Before scroll vertically]

As you can see the place enough, but it scroll veritically.

See screenshot#2:

[image: After scroll vertically]

Why it's scroll vertically? I don't want to scroll vertically when has enough place. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Replace:

this:

`app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`

by

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
```

for all items under item "android:id="@+id/textView". As result - no more vertical scroll.

But why this settings has affects for VERTICAL scroll?